# Removing $#x0 from string

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have a string that I'm trying to parse to XML like this:

```
XElement.Parse(XMLdata)
```

But the problem I'm having is that XMLdata contains this text:

> $#x0 resulting in the following exception : `'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 6554.` when trying to parse the string to XML.

Is there a way to remove those characters before calling `XElement.Parse(XMLdata)`?

Please assist

Comment: Could you post the XML you are trying to parse?

Comment: I found the answer:

I replaced the specific text with an empty string before parsing:

XElement.Parse(XMLData.Replace("&#x0", ""));
Solved my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: If it fails, that means the data is not a valid XML file. I highly advise you to ensure that the generated XML (whatever generate its) is a correct XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all special characters in your xml content before parse its

```
"
&
'
<
>
```

Comment: This seems to be a poor solution. I believe a solution that ensure the correctness of the XML where it is generated is a far better solution. Better than tweaking strings to force the parser to load the XML